# Snowplow event tracker throwing error when react native tracker is used

Tags: react-native, snowplow, expo-go

We have been trying to integrate react native tracker of snowplow in our app. The app is built on top of expo.
We have included all necessary libraries but while adding the tracker to one of the views,during the execution, we got the below error

`[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: createTracker: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSnowplowTracker.createTracker').]`

Can someone guide us to resolve this issue.

Comment: If snowplow react native SDK has native code (it probably does) and is not supported by Expo, then you can't use it within expo-go unless u build your project. I have the same problem with mixpanel

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So with mixpanel, are you taking the approach  taking the build each time. Do you know of any other side effects with this approach

Comment: We're currently deciding what to do, we started a week ago and then ran into this problem, so I have no hands-on experience to give you an answer.